# Bootstrap Input Group not rendering correctly inside jQuery UI dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a number field with 2 buttons on each side of it to increment/decrement.
It renders fine when not in a jQuery UI dialog , like so:

**Outside of Jquery Dialog:**

[image]

**Inside Jquery Dialog:**

[image]

**Code:**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group"> 
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" data-type="increment_FILEALERTMINS">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">
                        </i>
        </button>
      </div>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" required id="FILEALERTMINS" name="FILEALERTMINS" placeholder="Enter FILEALERTMINS"/>
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" data-type="decrement_FILEALERTMINS">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus">
                        </i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
  $(".form-group").dialog(); // comment this out to see it working properly!
})
```

**Reproducible Fiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/sajjansarkar/qr2zc4nj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/qr2zc4nj/2/

```js
$(function(){
  $(".form-group").dialog();
})
```

```css
.glyphicon{
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="FILEALERTMINS">
    FILEALERTMINS:
  </label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" data-type="increment_FILEALERTMINS">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">
      </i>
        </button>
      </div>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" required id="FILEALERTMINS" name="FILEALERTMINS" placeholder="Enter FILEALERTMINS"/>
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" data-type="decrement_FILEALERTMINS">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus">
      </i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You need to add `font-size` to .`glyphicon`.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems happening here :

1. The Bootstrap structure for the kind of form you're trying to create is incomplete.
2. You're binding jQuery UI's `dialog()` plugin on the `.form-group-element`, which adds jQuery UI CSS on it and breaks the style.
3. There are conflicting styles between jQuery UI and Bootstrap.

The first two are pretty easy to fix:

1. Add a `.form-horizontal` wrapper div around you entire HTML ([`form-horizontal` in Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms-horizontal))
2. Wrap the entire code in another, style-less `div` and bind `dialog()` on it instead (eg.: `$('#myForm').dialog()`).

For the third, you'll have to write custom CSS to undo what jQuery UI is doing.

You need to reset the right button size, which can be achieved by doing the following:

```
.ui-widget button.btn {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

And set the container width to 100% (jQuery UI appends a fixed width in pixels when it initializes `dialog()` on it):

```
#myForm {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

Unfortunately you'll have to keep the `!important` on as it's the only way to override inline styles.

Finally, you may want to add a `width` option to your dialog. Your label is pretty long and you need the dialog to be initially wider so the input doesn't overlap it.

```
$("#myForm").dialog({
  width: 700
});
```

Here's a [working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/93pjjxzq/).

As a rule of thumb, I always try to avoid mixing plugins that may have conflicting styles. jQuery UI comes with styles and it doesn't work really well with Bootstrap. If you want to keep your app clean, try to look into Bootstrap's own dialogs: [Modals](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals).